# Swift 3 Counting up timer failed to show the updated number in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel, nstimer

I have the following count up timer, but after i run the program, the UILable generate from 0 then to (). But the counter number is correct because i can see the printing log is correct. 
May I know what's going wrong with the code.`

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelForBinaryCount: UILabel!

    var timer = Timer()
    var counter = 0


    @IBAction func start() {

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target:self, selector: #selector(Resting.updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelForBinaryCount.text = String(counter)

    }

    func updateCounter() {
        labelForBinaryCount.text = String(describing: counter += 1)
        print(counter)
    }

    @IBAction func pauseButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    @IBAction func clearButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        timer.invalidate()
        counter = 0
        labelForBinaryCount.text = String(counter)
    }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
func updateCounter() {
    counter += 1
    labelForBinaryCount.text = String(counter)
    print(counter)
}
```

I think you understand. ;)